# Android service doesn't get started on opening the fragment

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, android-fragments, android-intent

I am implementing AWS shadow service in the android fragment.
The service intent does not start when I open the app.
Service intent is present in number 1 fragment.
when I switch the fragments from number 1 to number 2 and then back to number 1 - the service intent starts.
Any possible reason for this?

P.S
I stop the service intent in onPause() and onStop() of that fragment.
When I commented the code of  stopping the service intent then the service intent starts on opening the app

Comment: Can you share some code ?

Comment: Are you starting the service in onResume()?

Comment: @GhulamMoinulQuadir Cannot share due to NDA with company.

Comment: @KaranModi Yes. But when i open the app again after killing it, services are not initiated.

Comment: Well ideally onResume and onPause are paired and onStart and onStop are paired. In this case, try starting the service in onCreateView and stopping it in onDestroyView. Also make sure that each time the service starts, it's a 'clean' start.